# Report progress of running task using an image in java

Tags: java, progress

I am trying to execute a program which takes around **6-7 seconds** to execute after displaying GUI for the user. Problem here is that the user has to wait for 6-7 seconds without any processing or progress notification.

So want i am trying to do is that, while the **MainApp ma = new MainApp();** code executes, i want to display a **gif** picture for the user saying that the program is being executed. Displaying of picture code is written in 
**ShowProgressPic spp = new ShowProgressPic();**

I have a boolean datatype variable named **end** which will be set to true in the last statement of **MainApp()** constructor. When the execution of the **MainApp ma = new MainApp();** ends, i want to stop displaying the gif image.

Please help me out with this.
**Thank you.**

Comment: You need to give us more information: is this a Swing GUI (if so use a SwingWorker)? AWT? Other?

Comment: @Hovercraft Yes, i am using Swing GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're problem involves a Swing GUI, I would suggest that you use a SwingWorker to do the long-acting program execution in a background thread. Then when the thread is done, you have two or more ways of proceeding from there. You can have the SwingWorker call code in its done method to close the progress display or you can have the code that holds and executes the SwingWorker listen to the SwingWorker via a PropertyChangeListener and act when the state property is SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.

Answer (score 2):

look into threads. You would have to load the process in a different thread from the main therad to show the progress. For showing the progress you could use JProgressBar

here is a part-pseudocode example example with a output print for displaying percent:

```
int maxSufftoDo = 500;
new Thread() {
public void run() {
    while not done {
        do part of stuff;
        updateStatus(numOfStuffDone * 100 / maxStufftoDo);
    }
}
}.start();

public void updateStatus(int s) {
    System.out.println(i + "% done");
}
```

Comment: I tried using threads, but the gif image is being displayed right after executing the MainApp() rather than displaying the gif image while the MainApp() is being executed. No parallel processing is being done here.

Comment: @SRIKANTH: That means that you're attempt is incorrect, that you're not doing actual background threading. stas' recommendation is a valid one (1+ to him), and is pretty much the same as my own.

Comment: Actually, i cannot place my code in while loop since it has to run only once and i will not be able to determine the end of MainApp() execution initially because of the processing speed. In one system, my application runs little faster and in some system,s it will run slowly. That's the problem. I will try with @hovercraft solution with SwingWorker. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Events and Listeners for multithreading in GUI (and in general also recommended).

Comment: Yeah, i have a event and a listener in my program. I have a button in my GUI and when user clicks on that, the event is fired and listener is executed. In the listener part only i have written the above code of MainApp and showProgressPic.